# Handling JSON response from a Django QuerySet via AJAX

Tags: javascript, json, django, ajax

I am passing a Django QuerySet as a JSON response from a Django view.

```
def loadSelectedTemplate(request):
   
    if request.is_ajax and request.method == "GET":
        
        templateID = request.GET.get("templateID", None)
        
        template = list(operationTemplates.objects.filter(templateID = templateID))
        
        if operationTemplates.objects.filter(templateID = templateID).exists():
           
            ser_template = serializers.serialize('json', template )
            return JsonResponse({"valid": True, "template": ser_template}, status=200)
        else:
            
            return JsonResponse({"valid": False}, status = 200)
```

This response is received by the javascript and it can be logged to the console.

```
// GET AJAX request
        $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: "{% url 'loadSelectedTemplate' %}",
            data: {"templateID": templateID},
            success: function (response) {
                // if valid template, add to textarea
                if (response["valid"]){
                    var template = response["template"];
                    console.log(response);
                }
```

Console.log output for the JSON object looks like this;

```
{
    "valid": true,
    "template": "[{\"model\": \"opnoteannotator.operationtemplates\", 
        \"pk\": 14, 
        \"fields\": {\"templateCategory\": \"Lower Limb\", 
                     \"templateName\": \"Femoral to below knee Bypass using autologous vein\", 
                     \"templatePreopBundle\": \"WHO check list completed.\\r\\n
                                                Antibiotic Chemoprophylaxis: Co-amoxiclav / Teicoplanin / Gentamicin\", 
                    \"templateIndication\": \"CLTI with night pain / rest pain / tissue loss / infection\",
```

I want to add the objects in "fields" to a text-area on my web page.
How can I achieve this? I have tried different methods but can't seem to get the values accessed in the Javascript.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to convert to the AJAX input from the view.py to a JSON object even though I was passing it as a JsonResponse.

This solution seems to work.

```
 // GET AJAX request
        $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: "{% url 'loadSelectedTemplate' %}",
            data: {"templateID": templateID},
            success: function (response) {
                // if valid template, add to textarea
                if (response["valid"]){

                    //var template = response["template"];
                    var tem = response.template;

                    //convert to JSON object
                    var res = JSON.parse(tem);

                    //Empty text area
                    document.getElementById("opnoteTextArea").value =""

                    //Display in text area
                    document.getElementById("opnoteTextArea").value += "Template Name: " + res[0].fields.templateName;
                    document.getElementById("opnoteTextArea").value += "\n\nPreopBundle:\n" + res[0].fields.templatePreopBundle;
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try:

```
console.log(response['template']);
```

Comment: Dear Juwaini, many thanks for your answer. I can console log the template. But I am unable to access individual elements under "fields. like "templateName", "templateIndication" etc.